# PDO: Prepared statements with PHP Constants

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an SQL query that has many different parameters. Usually, in a PDO statement is would simply do:

```
$sql = '... :parameter ...';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':parameter', $var, $type);
```

However, I happen to have a large number of parameters, all of which happen to be PHP constants (so no user input).

There are two appraoches here:

1. Declare a variable for every parameter that we wish to bind, and pass that (as above).
2. Split the SQL query so that we have something like:

`$sql = '... ' . const . ' ...';`

The downside of *1* is that there is a lot of extra code which serves very little practical purpose, although it is clear what is going on.

The downside of *2* is that the syntax highlighting on the SQL code is lost and it just looks weird, although it is shorter and more concise.

Is there any way to pass those constants *as-is* to `bindParam()`?

So:

```
$query->bindParam(':parameter', CONST, $type);
```

Comment: Not using `bindParam()`, but using `bindValue()`: note that bindParam() arguments are passed to PDO by reference, whereas bindValue() arguments are passed by value

Comment: I would create a Mapping method, and probably a build query method

Comment: Pass the parameters as an array in execute().See [**PDO info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)